# Sort array by string from db

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have array like

```
$dashboard = array('amount' => 'Przypis (z anulacjami)', 'incaso' => 'Inkaso', 'commission' => 'Prowizja', 'contracts' => 'Kontrakty', 'contracts1' => 'Kontrakty kwartalne', 'contracts2' => 'Megakonkurs', 'unpaid' => 'Nierozliczone polisy gotówkowe', 'statuses' => 'Akredytacje');
```

And i got from db sorted keys like

```
contracts2,incaso,commission,contracts,contracts1,amount,unpaid,statuses
```

And i want sort array or attach value for this keys from Dashboard array and get

```
array('contracts2' => 'Megakonkurs',  'incaso' => 'Inkaso', 'commission' => 'Prowizja', 'contracts' => 'Kontrakty', 'contracts1' => 'Kontrakty kwartalne','amount' => 'Przypis (z anulacjami)', 'unpaid' => 'Nierozliczone polisy gotówkowe', 'statuses' => 'Akredytacje');
```

Im looking for the best solution. I can do it by foreach but i think there are better way. Thanks :)

Comment: you can use sort function of php [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sort.asp)

Comment: Its just sorting array by alphabetical order...

Comment: edit answer and add expected output too...

Comment: Just read everything one more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dashboard = array('amount' => 'Przypis (z anulacjami)', 'incaso' => 'Inkaso', 'commission' => 'Prowizja', 'contracts' => 'Kontrakty', 'contracts1' => 'Kontrakty kwartalne', 'contracts2' => 'Megakonkurs', 'unpaid' => 'Nierozliczone polisy gotówkowe', 'statuses' => 'Akredytacje');

$order = explode(',', 'contracts2,incaso,commission,contracts,contracts1,amount,unpaid,statuses');

$ordered_array = array_merge(array_flip($order), $dashboard);
```

Credits (and two more methods to accomplish the same): https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-order-in-a-secondary-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by the key you can use `ksort()`, like so:

```
$dashboard = array('amount' => 'Przypis (z anulacjami)', 'incaso' => 'Inkaso', 'commission' => 'Prowizja', 'contracts' => 'Kontrakty', 'contracts1' => 'Kontrakty kwartalne', 'contracts2' => 'Megakonkurs', 'unpaid' => 'Nierozliczone polisy gotówkowe', 'statuses' => 'Akredytacje');
ksort($dashboard);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Bdq5D)

If you want to sort by the value use `asort()` instead.